# What is the meaning of this code

Tags: c++, c

I found following code in one of the frameworks we are using,

```
if (nValue + 0.01 > nLimit)
   nValue = nValue - 0.01;

if (((nValue+1) / (int)(nValue+1)) == 1)
      sprintf(szValue, "%0.0f", nValue);
   else
      sprintf(szValue, "%0.2f", nValue);
```

what is the meaning of this code

Comment: This must be specific to your framework and requirement.

Comment: What is `nValue` representing?

Comment: I hate it when people use floats to represent money... I'd hate to be the guy who gets sued because he still owns €0.01 years after one payment due to obscure roundoff errors...

Comment: @Alexandre, indeed, and this code is a perfect example of the idiotic types of errors that lead to that. Here, there is no code to check that `nValue - 0.01 != nValue`... And of course `(int)(nValue+1)` has undefined behavior unless you know `nValue+1` fits into an `int` after rounding.

Comment: To be sure, it was only my guess that we're dealing with money here. The OP gave us no clues. It looks like poorly written code in any case.

Comment: here nValue represents system performance counter(RAM,SWAP Usage) consmption in terms of percentage of total

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suspect that the first part is a mistaken attempt to ensure nValue does not exceed nLimit. It possibly should be

```
if (nValue + 0.01 > nLimit)
   nValue = nLimit - 0.01;
```

In other words, if nValue is closer than 0.01 to the limit make it 0.01 less than the limit

---

To explain how the second part works, it involves dividing a floating point number by the integer part of the number. If the number is an integer then the result will be 1

e.g.

```
23.00 / 23 = 1 - It's an integer
23.05 / 23 = 1.002 - It's not an integer
```

Adding 1 to each side is (as ufukgun noticed) to prevent devide by zero, but the devision is redundant as you could simply compare the float with the int

```
if (nValue == (int)nValue)
```

Answer (score 4):

- Assuming the code is dealing with money amounts stored in floats, the first IF is subtracting 1 cent from nValue if that value exceeds a certain limit. I can't say anything about the purpose without more context.
- The second chunk deals (awkwardly) with displaying a value without decimal places if it's a straight "Dollar" amount, and other values with two decimal places.

Comment: Presumably the third chunk (not shown) takes the penny from the first chunk and transfers it to the framework developer's retirement fund.

Answer (score 1):

The first part tests whether nValue <= (nLimit - 0.01) and then reduces it by 0.01 if this is not the case.

The second part tests to see whether a float value corresponds to an integer and then prints it as an integer if so (e.g. `42`), otherwise prints it with two decimal places (e.g. `42.01`).

Answer (score 1):

```
if (nValue + 0.01 > nLimit)
   nValue = nValue - 0.01;
```

Without some context it's difficult to understand the purpose of this code. It seems to be trying to ensure that `nValue` is at least 0.01 less than `nLimit`, but `nValue - 0.01` may still be greater than `nLimit` and the code doesn't attempt to detect this case. Is `nLimit` the maximum value of the type? If not, what is it?

```
if (((nValue+1) / (int)(nValue+1)) == 1)
      sprintf(szValue, "%0.0f", nValue);
   else
      sprintf(szValue, "%0.2f", nValue);
```

This is trying to work out if `nValue` is a whole number. If it is a whole number, store just the integer portion of the number as a string. Otherwise store the value with two decimal places.

Comment: ues nLimit is the maximum value of this type, it is less than 100

Answer (score 0):

I think nValue is supposed to be greater than 0.

nValue+1 are used for case nValue == 0

---

```
if (((nValue+1) / (int)(nValue+1)) == 1)
```

means nValue is an integer. (like 45.00)

so developer wanted to print different for cases integer and float.

Comment: I think your first part is wrong, but the second spot on

Answer (score 0):

```
/* min limit of nValue is nLimit */
if (nValue + 0.01 > nLimit) nValue = nValue - 0.01;

/* if nValue is a round number(no floating point value) or zero eg. 4.00 */
if (((nValue+1) / (int)(nValue+1)) == 1) 

sprintf(szValue, "%0.0f", nValue); 

/* nValue has floating point value eg. 5.002 */
else 
sprintf(szValue, "%0.2f", nValue);
```

Hope this may help you

Comment: Note that the limiting code is incorrect if that is indeed what it's trying to do. Try `nValue = 100.0` and `nLimit = 1.0`.

Comment: @delty, you are right, i have make a change. nLimit should be a lowerLimit or threashold, not max